# How to ignore update or insert join if NULL value

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have a entity bean with a relation @ManyToOne that is in join on one column.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "work_order")
public class WorkOrder implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "sequenceGenerator")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "sequenceGenerator")
private Long id;

@NotNull
@Column(name = "id_order", nullable = false)
private String idOrder;

@Column(name = "description")
private String description;

@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
@Column(name = "status")
private StatusOrder status;

@Column(name = "creation_date")
private Instant creationDate;

@Column(name = "closing_date")
private Instant closingDate;

@Column(name = "client_id")
private Long clientId;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST) @NotFound (action = NotFoundAction.IGNORE)
@Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN)
@JoinColumn(name = "account",  insertable = false, updatable = false, nullable = true)
private AnagraficaClienti account;
```

And the second Entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "es_account")
public class AnagraficaClienti implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;


// da rimettere a @NotNull 
@Column(name = "fk_cod_azienda", nullable = true)
private String fk_cod_azienda;
@Id
@NotNull
@Column(name = "account", nullable = false)
private String account;
// da rimettere a @NotNull
@Column(name = "tipo_cli_for", nullable = true)
private String tipoClienteFornitore;

@Column(name = "tipo_account", nullable = true)
private String tipoAccount;
....
```

The "es_account" table has three not nullable primary key(fk_cod_azienda, account, tipo_cli_for) and the relation with the "work_order" table is by account column.

My problem is that sometimes it is possible that the user insert or update WorkOrder with a null account value and that is not avoid by AnagraficaClienti entity because it expects a non null(and not duplicate) value.

Are there any possible way to bypass the join with AnagraficaClienti when account is null?

Comment: Just move the relation to AnagraficaClienti class and change to @OneToMany. Make the relation nullable. When you just want to insert WorkOrder, do it. When you want to create the relation, add the managed entity WorkOrder to the list of work orders, which is owned by appropriate AnagraficaClienti

Comment: @thanhngo  Do you mean change create a relation to WorkOrder in AnagraficaClienti with the OneToMany annotation? Can you make an example with code please

Comment: Please see my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my point of view, @ManyToOne is violate OOP design principle due to the creation of redundant relation. Instead, i always create a @OneToMany relation with a list of related entities. To specify the relation as nullable, just add the **nullable=true** property in @JoinColumn. With @ManyToOne, you must specify property **optional=true**. Lets try and see if it works.

**WorkOrder**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "work_order")
public class WorkOrder implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "sequenceGenerator")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "sequenceGenerator")
private Long id;

@NotNull
@Column(name = "id_order", nullable = false)
private String idOrder;

@Column(name = "description")
private String description;

@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
@Column(name = "status")
private StatusOrder status;

@Column(name = "creation_date")
private Instant creationDate;

@Column(name = "closing_date")
private Instant closingDate;

@Column(name = "client_id")
private Long clientId;
```

**AnagraficaClienti**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "es_account")
public class AnagraficaClienti implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;


// da rimettere a @NotNull 
@Column(name = "fk_cod_azienda", nullable = true)
private String fk_cod_azienda;
@Id
@NotNull
@Column(name = "account", nullable = false)
private String account;
// da rimettere a @NotNull
@Column(name = "tipo_cli_for", nullable = true)
private String tipoClienteFornitore;

@Column(name = "tipo_account", nullable = true)
private String tipoAccount;

@OneToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE} )
@JoinColumn(name = "account", nullable = true)
private List<WorkOrder> workOrders;
```

When you want to insert the work order to the database:

```
workOrderRepository.save(workOrder);
```

When you want to create the relationship:

```
AnagraficaClienti client = anagraficaClientiRepository.findById(...);
client.getWorkOrders().add(newWorkOrder);
```

Comment: @puyabahrani Could you mark my answer as correct please?